# Elasticsearch Multi-Field With 'Raw' Value Not Being Created

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to add an un-analyzed version of an analyzed field, as a 'raw' multi-field, as per the ElasticSearch documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/multi-fields.html

This seems to be a common, well-supported pattern.

I've created the following index / field :

```
{ 
 "person": {  
    "aliases": {},   
    "mappings": {   
       "employee": {   
       "properties": {      
            "userName": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                       "type": "string",
                       "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
    } 
 }
```

If I query the index directly, i.e. GET /person, I see the mapping as I've posted above, so I'm confident that there wasn't a syntax error, etc.

However, when we're pushing data into the index, a userName.raw field is not being created.

```
{
  "_index": "person",    
  "_type": "employee",    
  "_id": "2",    
  "_version": 1,   
  "found": true,    
  "_source": {    
  "username": "Test Value"    
  }     
}
```

Anyone see something I'm missing?

Thanks!

EDIT:
This was a novice mistake when creating my index.

```
PUT person
{
  "person": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "employee": {
        "properties": {
          "email": {
```

Notice the person key is being PUT in the 'person' index.  This was creating a nested person.

Correct syntax is to remove the extra "person"

```
PUT person
    {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
          "employee": {
            "properties": {
              "email": {
```

Please see Linoy.M.K's answer, as he is correct.
The 'raw' field will not appear when retrieving a record by ID.  Its only useful as part of a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding multiple analyzers will not modify your source document means your source document will always have username only not username.raw

Added analyzers are useful when you do searching, means you can now search with username and username.raw to achieve different behavior like below.

```
  GET /person/employee/_search
    {
        "query": {
            "match": {
               "username": "Te"
            }
        }
    }

GET /person/employee/_search
        {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                   "username.raw": "Test Value"
                }
            }
        }
```